# Drawing two shapes on one image

Tags: image, matlab, binary, draw

This is part of what I have done for drawing a shape on my images:

> ```
> ...
> ...
> k = convhull(x,y);
> I=imread('img.png');
> imshow(I)
> hold on
> plot(x(k),y(k),'r-',x,y,'b+');
> BW = roipoly(I, x(k), y(k) );
> ```

What should I do in order to receive the binary result as in `BW`, but that contains the other shape (i.e; `xx`, `yy`)?

I kept `hold on`, and was able to `plot` the second shape, but the issue was how to get the binary result of the two shapes at the image.

**EDIT**

This is what I did:

```
I=imread('img.png');
....
....
selectedRegions1=119;
bb = vertcat( rg( selectedRegions1 ).BoundingBox );
bb(:,3:4) = bb(:,1:2) + bb(:,3:4) - 1;
totBB = [min( bb(:,1:2), [], 1 ), max( bb(:,3:4), [], 1 ) ]
nVal=50;
totBB =

  239.5000  202.5000  252.5000  211.5000

xx1 =239.5000 + rand(nVal,1).*(252.5000- 239.5000);
yy1 =   202.5000 + rand(nVal,1).*(211.5000-  202.5000);
k1 = convhull(xx1,yy1);
I=imread('img.png');
imshow(I)
hold on
plot(xx1(k1),yy1(k1),'r-',xx1,yy1,'b+');
fill(xx1(k1),yy1(k1),[1 1 1])
selectedRegions2=[181,186,193,198];
bb = vertcat( rg( selectedRegions2 ).BoundingBox );
bb(:,3:4) = bb(:,1:2) + bb(:,3:4) - 1;
totBB = [min( bb(:,1:2), [], 1 ), max( bb(:,3:4), [], 1 ) ]

totBB =

  355.5000  100.5000  399.5000  146.5000

xx2 =355.5000 + rand(nVal,1).*(399.5000- 355.5000);
yy2 =   100.5000 + rand(nVal,1).*( 146.5000-   100.5000);
k2 = convhull(xx2,yy2);
plot(xx2(k2),yy2(k2),'r-',xx2,yy2,'b+');
fill(xx2(k2),yy2(k2),[1 1 1])
BW = roipoly( I, xx1(k1), yy1(k1) );
BW = roipoly( I, xx2(k2), yy2(k2) );
imshow(BW)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is a binary result of two shapes? Please provide a complete code example, what is `x` and `y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polygon region has already been described by your `x(k)` and `y(k)`, so there is no more interactive part for you to draw another polygon. `imshow(BW)` is the same as your previous 3 lines code.

You can save/`imwrite` the `BW` and `imread` it again , then use `roipoly` to draw your own polygons.

If you draw the polygons all automatically, you can just use:

```
BW = roipoly( I, xx1(k1), yy1(k1) ); 
BW1 = roipoly( I, xx2(k2), yy2(k2) ); 
imshow(BW|BW1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that. I have written (saved) the first binary image, then, read it again, and drew the next shape. For the second `BW`, when I `imshow` the image, it is as I expect. But, when I write (save) it, read it, and show it, I just see the second shape, although the draw was on the first binary image that included the first shape. How can I write the second image, such that it contains both shapes?

Comment: @Simplicity  When you draw the polygons after re-imread the image, use [bw1, xi,yi]=roipoly(bw), the coordinates that you selected will be recorded in xi and yi vectors. Thanks

Comment: It seems I should draw those coordinates manually? As the region is small and not easy to draw by hand. Or, I may be missing something?

Comment: you can draw the polygons manually if you like. You can zoom in during the drawing process. Just click on the + on the fig

Comment: Isn't there a way to `plot` the shape as I did with the first shape? As it would be more accurate in my case

Comment: then use the same method BW = roipoly(I, x(k), y(k) ); if you know x(k) and y(k). actually you don't need to save and re-imread if all your job is done automatically instead of manually.

Comment: Please see my **edit**. I'm having the issue with `BW` at the last steps. I just get one shape displayed, and not the two. What should I do in this case?

Comment: BW = roipoly( I, xx1(k1), yy1(k1) );
BW2 = roipoly( BW, xx2(k2), yy2(k2) );

Comment: I tried your suggestion. When I `imshow` `BW`, I get the first shape. When I `imshow` `BW2`, I get the second shape, provided that `BW` **just** contains the first shape, and `BW2` **just** contains the second shape, and not the two shapes

Comment: Does `hold on` have to do with that? As that was done under `hold on`

Comment: Try this: BW = roipoly( I, xx1(k1), yy1(k1) ); BW1 = roipoly( I, xx2(k2), yy2(k2) ); imshow(BW|BW1)

Comment: That is exactly it! And, I used `imwrite(BW|BW1,.....`) to save the image. Can you kindly put this answer in your answer, so I mark it as `accepted`? Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind support. Appreciate it!